# Map result from SQL query using param

Tags: java

I want to implement this ruby logic into Java code:

```
.take(10).map(&:serial_number)
```

I have a result from SQL query which is a List with Object: `List<Connections>`:

How I can take the first 10 list elements and group them via field `serial_number`?

Comment: Why isn't the grouping done via GROUP BY in SQL?

Comment: can you show the expected output for those 10 elements after grouping by

Comment: is `serial_number` a field of the `Connections` class? Is there a getter for it? Is the class Connections or Connection?

Comment: @Bentaye the class is `Connections` and yes to all

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it's already done into the SQL query but I want to add it tinot the Java code as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can `map()` method in a `stream()` of this list and finally collect it. And for the limit, there is a `limit()` method. An example:

```
public class Example {
    static class Person {
        private String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person("John");
        Person p2 = new Person("Mike");
        Person p3 = new Person("Peter");
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3);

        List<String> namesOfPersons = persons.stream().map(Person::getName).limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList());
        namesOfPersons.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

will output:

```
John
Mike
```

Answer (score 1):

Would that do what you expect?

```
    Map<String, List<Connections>> map =
            connectionsList.stream()
            .limit(10)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Connections::getSerialNumber));
```

It takes the 10 first elements of your list and creates a Map

Each key is a different serialNumber and each value is a list of the Connections with that serialNumber

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of the `List<Connections>` object is `connections` and the getter function for `serial_number` is `getSerialNumber`, you could do something like this:

```
Map<String, List<Connections>> groupedConnections = connections.stream().limit(10).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Connections::getSerialNumber));
```

That will yield a `Map` (which is similar to a `Hash` in Ruby, if I'm correct) which will contain as keys, the `serial_number` which is grouped by, and as values, a `List` of `Connections` for each corresponding `serial_number`. Only the first 10 elements will be picked from the `connections` list.